# sed find and insert after or replace

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to add a word into a file using a bash script. Specifically, I want a line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to go from

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

to

```
hosts:          files wins dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

I have been trying with `sed`, but had no luck. I can't figure out how to search for a word and replace it or insert a word in that file.

Comment: try `sed 's/files mdns4_minimal/files wins dns mdns4_minimal/g'`

Comment: What exactly do you want to search for and replace? If you want to just insert text after a specific field, e.g. files, `awk` might be a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the parts you don't want to change.

```
sed 's/^\(hosts:  *files\) \(mdns4_minimal\)/\1 wins dns \2/' input.file
```

- `\(...\)` creates a capture group, while `\1` references the first capture group, `\2` the second one, etc.
- `^` matches at the beginning of a line.
- `*` means "the previous thing repeated zero or more times". I was too lazy to count the spaces.
- add the option `-i` if you want to make the changes in place of the file, to create also a backup copy of the original file add `-i.bak` or `-i.default`.

Comment: I added the `-i` in order to add the filename; sed -i 's/^\(hosts:  *files\) \(mdns4_minimal\)/\1 wins dns \2/' /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: @eekfonky, the option `-i` has different meaning. I've updated the answer.